# Java XML Binding library that doesnt create instances from elements directly but calls a factory

Tags: java, xml

I have a simple xml file and would like to have different complex type call a factory w/ the parameters rather than creating a concrete class directly.

I would rather use something like XMLBeans w/ factory support rather than writing my own DOM or SAX code. From what I can tell Apache Digester iteself is also not a solution...

Comment: Have you looked at JAXB?

Answer (score 0):

The following articles may help you do what you want with JAXB:

Instantiate object with parameters:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html

Leveraging the ObjectFactory:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/moxy-jaxb-map-interfaces-to-xml.html